# How can i simulate a Back-Button click

Tags: android, back-button, robotium

so i was working with Robotium to automate tests and i'm having a little problem. Robotium is able to "sendkey(keyevent.keycode_back)" so i can return from a view to the previous but now there is another (android native) activity which opens when i click on "forgotten password" (hyperlink) and i would require android itself to simulate a back button click. is there a way to do so?

As for the code i'm working on:

```
@FlakyTest(tolerance = 2)
public void testperformMsgListItemandItemSelectTestAfterStartInLandscape_ShouldSucceed() throws Exception{
    try {

        mSolo.clickOnText("Forgotten Password?");
        assertFalse(mSolo.getCurrentActivity().hasWindowFocus());
        mSolo.sendKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);
        assertTrue(mSolo.getCurrentActivity().hasWindowFocus());
        mSolo.clickOnText("Register Now!");
        assertFalse(mSolo.getCurrentActivity().hasWindowFocus());

    } catch (AssertionError err) {
        mSolo.fail(getName(), err);
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to work it like the back button is pressed?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `KeyEvent` and dispatch it.

For example:

```
KeyEvent kdown = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(kdown);
```

an alternative method is to just call `finish()` in your activity. That disposes of the current activity and takes you back to the previous activity, which is exactly what the Android OS does when you click the back button.

Comment: well i get an error saying "cannot make a static reference to the non-static method dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent) from the type Activity"

Comment: @jaytj95 What if the foreground activity doesn't belong to me, is it possible to simulate the back key press and forward it?

Answer (score 1):

If the current activity belongs to the app you're testing, use

```
mSolo.goBack();
```

Robotium cannot perform any actions if the current activity belongs to another app, so to write useful tests you can't ever let your tests launch other apps.

Comment: i know that robotium is not able to use goBack() on other applications. the problem is that as soon as i click on forgot password android itself ask me if i want to use google chrome browser or internet which does not belong to the app anymore. thats why im searching for a method to make the whole mobile use the back button

Comment: Your test can't click on forgot password. 1) If you run it on a device with just one browser that would go straight to that browser. 2) On your device that chooser doesn't belong to your app so Robotium can't get back out of it.

Comment: And I cannot use eclipse to make android use the back button? even without permissions it is not possible?

Comment: No, and since the web page you're trying to test isn't part of your native app, you're better off not testing it. Focus on testing what's in your app.

Answer (score 0):

if >=API LEVEL5:

```
   super.onBackPressed()
```

else

```
    KeyEvent kdown = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
    Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(kdown);
```

Comment: same as the comment below you: "cannot make a static reference to the non-static method dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent) from the type Activity"